# smallest value greater than N in fibonacci series in python

Tags: python

I am looking to solve this question from the other practice website. I am new to python.
with considering a Fibonacci series as  `1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89...` I want to print the (1) Fibonacci series whose values do not exceed N (for example N=10), find the sum of the even-valued terms.

(2) And the smallest value greater than N.

I have write the following code:

```
N = 10
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in fibonacci_cashe: 
        return fibonacci_cashe[n]
    if n==1:
        value = 1
    elif n == 2:
        value = 1
    elif n>2:
        value = fibonacci(n-2)+fibonacci(n-1)

    fibonacci_cashe[n] = value
    return value 
for i in range(N):
    test = fibonacci(N)
    #I don't know what I should do here
```

For example, for N=10:

the series is `1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89, 144, 144+89, ...`
the even less than (N=10) are: `2, 8, 34` and sum of them is 44.
the smallest greater than (N=10) is : `13`

Could you help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1) can you add the expected values? 2) can you format the number of questions? It seems like you're asking 3 questions: print Fib series whose values do not exceed N, sum of the even values, and smallest value greater than N. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: `value = fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-1)` should be `value = fibonacci(n-2)+fibonacci(n-1)`.  As it is, you're just doubling the previous term rather than adding the previous two terms.  Also, "cache" is spelled "cache", not "cashe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fibonacci(n):
   if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
   return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)


N = 10
result = []
total = 0
smallest = 1
for i in range(1, N + 1):
   term = fibonacci(i)
   if term < N:
        result.append(fibonacci(i))
        # also sum the even valued term
        if term % 2 == 0:
            total += term
    else:
        # term exceeded the limit N
        # so the term for which we exceeded the limit
        # is actually the smallest term greater than N
        # or you can say it is the first term which is greater than N
        smallest = term
        break
print(*result)
print('sum of even terms :', total)
print('smallest value greater than N:', smallest)
```

**With memoization**

```
def fibonacci(n):
if n == 1 or n == 2:
    fibonacci_cashe[n] = 1
if fibonacci_cashe[n] != 0:
    return fibonacci_cashe[n]

fibonacci_cashe[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
return fibonacci_cashe[n]


N = 10
fibonacci_cashe = [0]*N # for memorization
result = []
total = 0
smallest = 1
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    term = fibonacci(i)
    if term < N:
        result.append(fibonacci(i))
        # also sum the even valued term
        if term % 2 == 0:
            total += term
    else:
        # term exceeded the limit N
        # so the term for which we exceeded the limit
        # is actually the smallest term greater than N
        # or you can say it is the first term which is greater than N
        smallest = term
        break
print(*result)
print('sum of even terms :', total)
print('smallest value greater than N:', smallest)
```

**Output**

```
1 1 2 3 5 8
sum of even terms : 10
smallest value greater than N: 13
```

Comment: Why did you remove the memoization?  This will run hideously slowly for large n.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks for pointing it out.  I thought it would add extra complexity to the answer. However, I added an alternative solution with memorization now.

Comment: There's no "r" in "memoization".  The root word is "memo", not "memorize".  You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. English is not my first language. Thanks a lot.